# How to get a specific information in wikipedia with ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api, wikipedia

How to get the information that is always shown in the right box in the vast majority of searches (the one shown in the image) with AJAX? I already used the API https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php but I do not find as such the information I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, omg, I never spend this much time for answering a question on stackoverflow,

so you have a working snippet below, it's dirty but it's working :)

```js
// wikipedia article (in url)
const wiki_article_title = 'Grand_Theft_Auto_V';

// please check https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Get_the_contents_of_a_page
const url_api = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=${wiki_article_title}&prop=text&formatversion=2&origin=*`;

function extractInfoboxFromWiki(doc) {
  // here we extract the json provided by api
  const json = doc.querySelector('pre');
  const obj = JSON.parse(json.innerText);
  let html = obj.parse.text;

  // for whatever reason '\n' substring are present in html text
  // so we remove them with a regex to not break 'JSON.parse()'
  html = html.replace(/\\n/gm, '');

  // get the interesting part of api reponse
  const node = document.createElement('div');
  node.innerHTML = html;
  const infobox = node.querySelector('.infobox');
  let infos = [...infobox.firstChild.children];

  let output = {};

  // parse title
  output['title'] = infos[0].querySelector('th').innerText;
  infos.shift();

  // parse image url
  output['image_url'] = infos[0].querySelector('a').getAttribute("href");
  infos.shift();

  // traverse the nodes to map captions with values
  infos.forEach( tr => {
    const key = tr.querySelector('th').innerText;

    if(tr.querySelector('ul')) {
      const lis = tr.querySelectorAll('li');
      const values = [...lis].map( li => li.innerText);
      output[key] = values;
    } else {
      const value = tr.querySelector('td').innerText;
      output[key] = value;
    }

  });

  // return beautified json
  return JSON.stringify(output, null, 4);
}

fetch(url_api)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');

    const WHAT_YOU_WANT = extractInfoboxFromWiki(doc);
    const formated = `<pre>${WHAT_YOU_WANT}</pre>`;

    document.write(formated);
  });
```

for GTA V article you get :

```json
{
    "title": "Grand Theft Auto V",
    "image_url": "/wiki/File:Grand_Theft_Auto_V.png",
    "Developer(s)": "Rockstar North[a]",
    "Publisher(s)": "Rockstar Games",
    "Producer(s)": [
        "Leslie Benzies",
        "Imran Sarwar"
    ],
    "Designer(s)": [
        "Leslie Benzies",
        "Imran Sarwar"
    ],
    "Programmer(s)": "Adam Fowler",
    "Artist(s)": "Aaron Garbut",
    "Writer(s)": [
        "Dan Houser",
        "Rupert Humphries",
        "Michael Unsworth"
    ],
    "Composer(s)": [
        "Tangerine Dream",
        "Woody Jackson",
        "The Alchemist",
        "Oh No"
    ],
    "Series": "Grand Theft Auto",
    "Engine": "RAGE",
    "Platform(s)": [
        "PlayStation 3",
        "Xbox 360",
        "PlayStation 4",
        "Xbox One",
        "Microsoft Windows",
        "PlayStation 5",
        "Xbox Series X/S"
    ],
    "Release": [
        "PS3, Xbox 360",
        "17 September 2013",
        "PS4, Xbox One",
        "18 November 2014",
        "Microsoft Windows",
        "14 April 2015",
        "PS5, Xbox Series X/S",
        "Q3/Q4 2021"
    ],
    "Genre(s)": "Action-adventure",
    "Mode(s)": "Single-player, multiplayer"
}
```

I thought my code will not work with different looking wiki page, but no, it's working anyway :

```js
// wikipedia article (in url)
const wiki_article_title = 'Richard_Stallman';

// please check https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Get_the_contents_of_a_page
const url_api = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=${wiki_article_title}&prop=text&formatversion=2&origin=*`;

function extractInfoboxFromWiki(doc) {
  // here we extract the json provided by api
  const json = doc.querySelector('pre');
  const obj = JSON.parse(json.innerText);
  let html = obj.parse.text;

  // for whatever reason '\n' substring are present in html text
  // so we remove them with a regex to not break 'JSON.parse()'
  html = html.replace(/\\n/gm, '');

  // get the interesting part of api reponse
  const node = document.createElement('div');
  node.innerHTML = html;
  const infobox = node.querySelector('.infobox');
  let infos = [...infobox.firstChild.children];

  let output = {};

  // parse title
  output['title'] = infos[0].querySelector('th').innerText;
  infos.shift();

  // parse image url
  output['image_url'] = infos[0].querySelector('a').getAttribute("href");
  infos.shift();

  // traverse the nodes to map captions with values
  infos.forEach( tr => {
    const key = tr.querySelector('th').innerText;

    if(tr.querySelector('ul')) {
      const lis = tr.querySelectorAll('li');
      const values = [...lis].map( li => li.innerText);
      output[key] = values;
    } else {
      const value = tr.querySelector('td').innerText;
      output[key] = value;
    }

  });

  // return beautified json
  return JSON.stringify(output, null, 4);
}

fetch(url_api)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');

    const WHAT_YOU_WANT = extractInfoboxFromWiki(doc);
    const formated = `<pre>${WHAT_YOU_WANT}</pre>`;

    document.write(formated);
  });
```